# AWS Lambda created from assets in CDK throws Class not found exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I'm trying to create and upload a lambda using the AWS CDK for Java. The following code is what I use to create the lambda in the Stack. However this throws a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` when trying to run the lambda.

```
    private fun createUserLambda(): Function {
        val dirPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")
        val lambdaDir = File("$dirPath/src/com/test/lambda")
        val props = FunctionProps.builder()
            .code(Code.fromAsset(File(lambdaDir, "handler").toString()))
            .handler(AddUser::class.java.canonicalName + "::" + AddUser::handleRequest.name)
            .runtime(Runtime.JAVA_8)
            .build()
        return Function(this, "UserCreateLambda", props)
    }
```

I can see that the code exists which I download the zip file from the S3 bucket created which contains the assets. Not entirely sure what's missing here but any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Hi @AsadSMalik did you able to solve your issue? I am facing with same problem

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer solved it

Comment: Awesome. Did you used Code.fromAsset() as well with pointing to a jar or used `CfnParametersCode.fromCfnParameters();` to create code object as shown in their example documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/codepipeline_example.html

Comment: I used `Code.fromAsset()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `Code.fromAsset()` call creates an artifact of source files. Lambda requires a compiled jar for Java runtimes.